# Accessing Sub Directories and Files Within System32 Using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I have the following code:

```
import os
print (os.listdir("C:/Windows/System32/config"))
print (os.listdir("C:/Windows/System32/winevt"))
```

I am running this Python script as an administrator and confirmed those directories in fact exist.

The first line outputs with some files and folders, but not all files. For example, there is a registry hive contained within called "SOFTWARE" which does not appear in the output.

The second line says the path wasn't identified. Here is the full output:

```
['Journal', 'RegBack', 'systemprofile', 'TxR']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    print (os.listdir("C:/Windows/System32/winevt"))
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:/Windows/System32/winevt'
```

This module (`os.listdir`), works pretty much everywhere else on the system, but not within System32. I suspect this may be permission related, but am not too sure on how to fix it as I am already running the script as an administrator.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: 32-bit programs run as WOW64 processes in 64-bit Windows. The WOW64 system uses redirection in the kernel to make the filesystem directory "%SystemRoot%\System32" actually reference "%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64" and the registry key "HKLM\Software" actually reference "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node".

Comment: @eryksun, yes, my mistake. forward slashes should be fine..that was a hurried comment:)

Comment: In 64-bit Windows 7+, we can access the real "System32" directory in WOW64 as "SysNative". This only works in a WOW64 process, however. In a native 64-bit process we have to use "System32".

Comment: Thanks guys! That definitely got me on the right track. Looks like this works:`print (os.listdir("C:/Windows/Sysnative/winevt/Logs"))` Thank you!